# Data is overridden when component renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using the following package:
react, redux, react-redux & redux-thunk

Here is my  component:

```
function Post({ individualPostItem, navigation }){

    const renderImage = () =>{
        let fileExtension;

        let myStuffToRender = () => individualPostItem.files.map((item, index) =>{

            let fileExtensionSplit = item.split('.');
            fileExtension = typeof(fileExtensionSplit !== 'undefined') && fileExtensionSplit[1];

            let fileToDisplay = s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", {Bucket: "my-bucket-name", Key:`${individualPostItem._id}/${item}`});
            if(fileExtension === "png" || fileExtension === "jpeg"){
                
                console.log("file: ", fileToDisplay); //here is where I'm getting 2 items printed.
                
                return(
                    <Image key={index} source={{uri: fileToDisplay}} />
                );
            }

        });
        
        
        if(typeof(individualPostItem.files) !== "undefined" && individualPostItem.files.length !== 0){

            return(
                <View>
                    {myStuffToRender()}
                </View>
            );
        }
        
}

export default Post;
```

I am using Post component in  screen:

```
function NewsFeed({ navigation, networkCallToExecute, networkCallParam ){

    const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts.allPosts);


    useEffect(() =>{

        navigation.addListener("focus", () =>{
            dispatch(networkCallToExecute(networkCallParam));
        });
    

    }, []);



    
    const myRenderItem = ( {item} ) =>{
        let postItem = item;


        return(
            <View>
                <Post individualPostItem={item} navigation={navigation} />
            </View>

        );


    };



    return(
        <View>
            <FlatList data={posts} keyExtractor={ (item, index) => index } renderItem={myRenderItem} />
        </View>
    );

}
```

The individualPostItem.files is an array [], I have 2 entries in that array:
**["abc.png", "def.png"]**

When the component first loads it prints the following:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3bucket_name/abc.png
http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3bucket_name/def.png

**My Question:**
How to have it such that when the component first loads it prints only the image loaded, not both images, for example the following:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3bucket_name/abc.png

How to fix that issue ?

Comment: If you only want the first item, why are you doing a `.map` over the whole array in `myStuffToRender()`? `.map` runs over every element in the array and returns an array.

Comment: Provided s3 image link, doesn't load, Can you fix that ?

Comment: I mean, the image link you have in the question doesn't load. Says `The specified bucket does not exist`

Comment: @samuei is there an alternative, I’m using it in react-native-swiper ?

Comment: @Abc123 Either rewrite `myStuffToRender` to only operate on the first element or only access the first element of the array that it returns.